# ListBox next line automatically in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How can I have the pictures go to next line when the first line is occupied?

Below is my current code:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <TextBlock Text="Picture" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="picList" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" Height="80" Width="80"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `WrapPanel` instead of the `StackPanel`. As Windows Phone 8 does not provide for a `WrapPanel` control, you need to use the **[Windows Phone Toolkit](https://phone.codeplex.com/)**.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <TextBlock Text="Picture" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="picList" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                           Width="300"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" Height="80" Width="80"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: WrapPanel does not exists.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your question was tagged with windows phone. You can get the WrapPanel from the Windows Phone Toolkit: https://phone.codeplex.com/